# How to simplify $\int \frac{-3}{2x^2-x-1} dx$ using log properties?

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

How can I rewrite the expression $\int \frac{-3}{2x^2-x-1} dx$ using log properties before solving for the integral?

I tried ln(-3)-ln(2x^2-x-1) but this doesn't seem to help. What do I do from here?